# Websocket via ssl

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, websocket

I have the following infrastructure:

[image]

When I access the Application via HTTP everythig works, but via HTTPs I am gettin:

[image]

and on the client site:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.bla.cz/tb-socket/444/qzdmw5ry/websocket' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected 
response code: 403
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you manually registering a dispatcher servlet? You indicate you are using Spring Boot that already registers this for you. If you want to use the existing XML file use `@ImportResource` on your application class.

Comment: I did that because I was getting same error: "Async support must be enabled on a servlet ..." So I registered DispatcherServlet to set registration.setAsyncSupported(true);

Comment: The property `asyncSupported` is `true` by default. So it isn't adding anything but complexity/confusion to your project. There must be a filter (or something like that) in your chain that doesn't have async enabled.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will remove that.